# Task scheduler is not running in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I've been working on a system in which task scheduler is used to run few applications every night. Recently i've noticed that the tasks which i scheduled are not running and it is giving the following error message

```
the scheduled task did not run because an incorrect password or user name was entered
```

Recently i've changed the system password. Is that the reason for the task scheduler failure?
Should i change the password in the task scheduler too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should change the password in Task Scheduler to match the password of the account it's executing code under.

If it can run with a less privileged account, I would take the opportunity to create an account with least privileges needed to complete it's work and setup Task Scheduler to use that restricted account.

Comment: so after i change the password should i right click on the task and choose run or will the task will run by itself at the scheduled time?

Comment: also if i have 5 tasks scheduled, should i change password for all the 5 tasks or will that work if i change the password for 1 task? pls reply soon

Comment: I don't have Windows XP available for reference, but I would think you need to change the credentials for each of your 5 tasks.  There should be a configuration item available for each task that lets you enter a user and password for the task to run as.

Comment: okay. so as i asked you earlier (in my first comment) should i right click and choose run to run the task after i change the password or will the task be executed automatically at scheduled time?